# Enable GPU resources (CUDA) on DC/OS

Tags: gpu, mesos, dcos

I have got a cluster with gpu nodes (nvidia) and deployed DC/OS 1.8. I'd like to enable to schedule jobs (batch and spark) on gpu nodes using gpu isolation.
DC/OS is based on mesos 1.0.1 that supports gpu isolation.

Comment: It would be great if you could extend your question with things you have already tried or found yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, DC/OS doesn't officially support GPUs in 1.8 (*experimental* support for GPUs will be coming in the next release as mentioned here: https://github.com/dcos/dcos/pull/766 ).

In this next release, only Marathon will officially be able to launch GPU services (Metronome (i.e. batch jobs) will not).

Regarding spark, the spark version bundled with Universe probably doesn't have GPU support for Mesos built in yet. Spark itself has it coming soon though: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14644

Comment: is there a document/reference that says Metronome doesn't support GPUs as yet?  I couldn't find one.  1.9.1 doesn't seem have to this support as well. 
 We too have a requirement to use scheduled based jobs instead of service based instances via marathon.

Answer (score 2):

In order to enable supporting gpu resources in DC/OS cluster the next steps are needed:

1. Configure mesos agents on gpu nodes:
   1.1. Stop *dcos-mesos-slave.service*:

   `systemctl stop dcos-mesos-slave.service`

   1.2. Add the next parameters into */var/lib/dcos/mesos-slave-common* file:

   `# a comma separated list of GPUs (id), as determined by running nvidia-smi on the host where the agent is to be launched
   MESOS_NVIDIA_GPU_DEVICES="0,1"`

   `# value of the gpus resource must be complied with  number of ids above
   MESOS_RESOURCES= [ {"name":"ports","type":"RANGES","ranges": {"range": [{"begin": 1025, "end": 2180},{"begin": 2182, "end": 3887},{"begin": 3889, "end": 5049},{"begin": 5052, "end": 8079},{"begin": 8082, "end": 8180},{"begin": 8182, "end": 32000}]}} ,{"name": "gpus","type": "SCALAR","scalar": {"value": 2}}]`

   `MESOS_ISOLATION=cgroups/cpu,cgroups/mem,disk/du,network/cni,filesystem/linux,docker/runtime,docker/volume,cgroups/devices,gpu/nvidia`

   1.3. Start *dcos-mesos-slave.service*:

   `systemctl start dcos-mesos-slave.service`
2. Enable the GPU_RESOURCES capability in mesos frameworks:

   2.1. *Marathon* framework should be launched with the option 
   `--enable_features "gpu_resources"`

   2.2. Aurora scheduler should be launched with the option `-allow_gpu_resource`

**Note.**

> Any host running a Mesos agent with Nvidia GPU support MUST have a valid Nvidia kernel driver installed. It is also highly recommended to install the corresponding user-level libraries and tools available as part of the Nvidia CUDA toolkit. Many jobs that use Nvidia GPUs rely on CUDA and not including it will severely limit the type of GPU-aware jobs you can run on Mesos.

Comment: would you happen to know how to set `--enable_features "gpu_resources"` for marathon framework. And to be clear, this is regarding marathon embedded into mesos, not the service you can run from universe correct?

Comment: There is no marathon embedded into mesos. There is the marathon embedded into the dcos. You can create a standalone marathon service   in dcos as well as on a standalone mesos cluster. To enable gpu_resources in the Marathon: 1) standalone mesos cluster: add to content in the file `/etc/marathon/conf/enable_features` the next: `,gpu_resources`; 2) for dcos you have to edit the marathon systemd unit file (`/etc/systemd/system/dcos-marathon.service`) by adding the option `--enable_features="gpu_resources"` into marathon daemon arguments (there may be a better way)