# Why is Mesos framework not being offered resources?

Tags: mesos

I am using Mesos 1.0.1. I have added an agent with a new role `docker_gpu_worker`. I register a framework with this role. The framework does not receive any offers. Other frameworks (same Java code) using other roles are working fine. I have not restarted the three Mesos masters. Does anyone have an idea about what might be going wrong?

At `master/frameworks`, I see my framework:

```
"{
  "id": "fd01b1b0-eb73-4d40-8774-009171ae1db1-0701",
  "name": "/data4/Users/mikeb/jobs/999",
  "pid": "scheduler-77345362-b85c-4044-8db5-0106b9015119@x.x.x.x:57617",
  "used_resources": {
    "disk": 0,
    "mem": 0,
    "gpus": 0,
    "cpus": 0
  },
  "offered_resources": {
    "disk": 0,
    "mem": 0,
    "gpus": 0,
    "cpus": 0
  },
  "capabilities": [],
  "hostname": "x-x-x-x.ec2.internal",
  "webui_url": "",
  "active": true,
  "user": "mikeb",
  "failover_timeout": 10080,
  "checkpoint": true,
  "role": "docker_gpu_worker",
  "registered_time": 1507028279.18887,
  "unregistered_time": 0,
  "principal": "test-framework-java",
  "resources": {
    "disk": 0,
    "mem": 0,
    "gpus": 0,
    "cpus": 0
  },
  "tasks": [],
  "completed_tasks": [],
  "offers": [],
  "executors": []
}"
```

At `master/roles` I see my role:

```
"{
  "frameworks": [
    "fd01b1b0-eb73-4d40-8774-009171ae1db1-0701",
    "fd01b1b0-eb73-4d40-8774-009171ae1db1-0673",
    "fd01b1b0-eb73-4d40-8774-009171ae1db1-0335"
  ],
  "name": "docker_gpu_worker",
  "resources": {
    "cpus": 0,
    "disk": 0,
    "gpus": 0,
    "mem": 0
  },
  "weight": 1
}"
```

At `master/slaves` I see my agent:

```
"{
  "id": "fd01b1b0-eb73-4d40-8774-009171ae1db1-S5454",
  "pid": "slave(1)@x.x.x.x:5051",
  "hostname": "x-x-x-x.ec2.internal",
  "registered_time": 1506692213.24938,
  "resources": {
    "disk": 35056,
    "mem": 59363,
    "gpus": 4,
    "cpus": 32,
    "ports": "[31000-32000]"
  },
  "used_resources": {
    "disk": 0,
    "mem": 0,
    "gpus": 0,
    "cpus": 0
  },
  "offered_resources": {
    "disk": 0,
    "mem": 0,
    "gpus": 0,
    "cpus": 0
  },
  "reserved_resources": {
    "docker_gpu_worker": {
      "disk": 35056,
      "mem": 59363,
      "gpus": 4,
      "cpus": 32,
      "ports": "[31000-32000]"
    }
  },
  "unreserved_resources": {
    "disk": 0,
    "mem": 0,
    "gpus": 0,
    "cpus": 0
  },
  "attributes": {},
  "active": true,
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "reserved_resources_full": {
    "docker_gpu_worker": [
      {
        "name": "gpus",
        "type": "SCALAR",
        "scalar": {
          "value": 4
        },
        "role": "docker_gpu_worker"
      },
      {
        "name": "cpus",
        "type": "SCALAR",
        "scalar": {
          "value": 32
        },
        "role": "docker_gpu_worker"
      },
      {
        "name": "mem",
        "type": "SCALAR",
        "scalar": {
          "value": 59363
        },
        "role": "docker_gpu_worker"
      },
      {
        "name": "disk",
        "type": "SCALAR",
        "scalar": {
          "value": 35056
        },
        "role": "docker_gpu_worker"
      },
      {
        "name": "ports",
        "type": "RANGES",
        "ranges": {
          "range": [
            {
              "begin": 31000,
              "end": 32000
            }
          ]
        },
        "role": "docker_gpu_worker"
      }
    ]
  },
  "used_resources_full": [],
  "offered_resources_full": []
}"
```

We have tracked the problem to this Mesos agent config:

```
--isolation="filesystem/linux,cgroups/devices,gpu/nvidia"
```

Removing that, the agent works properly, but without access to GPU resources. This config is a requirement according to the [docs](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/gpu-support/) for Nvidia GPU support and those docs seem to indicate that version 1.0.1 supports it. We are continuing to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GPU_RESOURCES` capability must be enabled for frameworks.

As illustrated in http://mesos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu-support/,
this can be achieved for example by specifying  `--framework_capabilities="GPU_RESOURCES"` in the `mesos-execute` command, or with code like this in C++:

```
FrameworkInfo framework;
framework.add_capabilities()->set_type(
    FrameworkInfo::Capability::GPU_RESOURCES);
```

For Marathon frameworks instead, the Marathon service must be started with the option `--enable_features "gpu_resources"` as indicated in [Enable GPU resources (CUDA) on DC/OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346321/enable-gpu-resources-cuda-on-dc-os)

Answer (score -1):

you can register the roles with master statically,
if you add an agent role at run time it would not be known to master
and it would require mesos master restart for master to see this role.
Try restarting the mesos master.

Comment: My understanding is that with version 1.0.1 that roles no longer need to be statically registered with the master. From the configuration docs: "--roles=VALUE, A comma-separated list of the allocation roles that frameworks in this cluster may belong to. This flag is deprecated; if it is not specified, any role name can be used."